# OleDbException was Unhandled: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: vb.net

```
con.Open()
            cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into tblEmp (FN,MN,LN,PAddHN,PAddSB,PAddMun,VPA,BD,BP,Tel,Rel,Cit,Height,Weight,Gend,SN,SOcc,NoC,AgeC,Stat,DS,FaN,FaOcc,MaN,MaOcc,PAdd,PTCN,PTCP,SSS,TIN,PHILH,PAGIBIG,CPNo,Sued,Age,BankAcc,empRfID,Principal,Department,Position,DRate,empID,OffT) Values('" & zfn & "','" & zmn & "','" & zln & "','" & zpaddhn & "','" & zpaddsb & "','" & zpaddmun & "','" & zvpa & "','" & zbd & "','" & zbp & "','" & ztel & "','" & zrel & "','" & zcit & "','" & zheight & "','" & zweight & "','" & zgend & "','" & zsn & "','" & zsocc & "','" & znoc & "','" & zagec & "','" & zstat & "','" & zds & "','" & zfan & "','" & zfaocc & "','" & zman & "','" & zmaocc & "','" & zpadd & "','" & zptcn & "','" & zptcp & "','" & zsss & "','" & ztin & "','" & zphilh & "','" & zpagibig & "','" & zcpno & "','" & zsued & "','" & zage & "','" & txtBankAcc.Text & "','" & zempRefID & "','" & cmbPrin.SelectedItem & "','" & cmbDept.SelectedItem & "','" & txtPos.Text & "','" & txtDRate.Text & "','" & empID & "','" & zOffTime & "')"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
```

I got an error when running this in my program.. but when i paste the command in my ms access query and it runs successfully. is there any problem  in my code? Pls help tnx.

Comment: Use parameters instead of string concatenation to prevent [sql-injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Answer (score 0):

where is your add parameter value?

You can try this

```
 Try
                    con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Dir\DB.accdb")
                    Dim command As String
                    command = "INSERT INTO Table (NOTIF, EMP_NO, EMP_NAME, [POSITION]) VALUES (@NOTIF, @EMP_NO, @EMP_NAME, @POSITION)"
                    con.Open()
                    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
                    cmd = New OleDbCommand(command, con)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOTIF", NOTIFTextBox.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMP_NO", EMP_NOTextBox.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMP_NAME", EMP_NAMETextBox.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POSITION", POSITIONTextBox.Text)

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch exceptionObject As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(exceptionObject.Message)
                Finally
                    con.Close()
                End Try
```

this code i have used before, it work perfectly

Also your name of the field look like contain illegal value to VB.net, so must like this

[Height],[Weight],.... You can try to check it in you DATASET > Configure > Select Statement > Insert and you will look the illegal value.
Just like my POSITION field, it was illegal, so must contain "[]"

Answer (score 0):

You may not use the "'", if the datatype is something like numbers. If i interprete it correctly, some of your fields are numbers.

```
con.Open()
cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into tblEmp (someInt, someString) VALUES (12, 'asdf')"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

Beside this, you should get the same error in Acces, if you run you Query again. Use the debugger and add a Breakpoint at the "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()" to get the finished query command string with all "'".